# Custom Identity Types in Mapping

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, mapping

I have an application where the identity column is stored as an Oracle VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) but is actually a Guid.  I want my model to expose it as a Guid:

```
class Foo
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Using Fluent NHibernate I don't see a CustomTypeIs() method on the IIdentityPart.  I would think it would be something similar to an IUserType, but I can't find the correlation.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabio Maulo noted that this is [governed by the DataProvider](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/msg/bc11566cf61c6c30) on the NHibernate Users mailing list.